# 2345 mistake in Typescript at event.target.value In React event

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events, checkbox

I just started styding TypeScript and unfortunately I could not find solution of my problem.
I have a list of checkbox. I add the value of unchecked checkboxes into the array.
But TS shows mistake on **event.target.value** *Argument of type 'any' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.*

Checkbox

```
<Checkbox
              className={classes.checkbox}
              icon={item.icon}
              onClick={props.switchType}
              checkedIcon={item.icon}
              name="checkedH"
              value={item.title}
              color="primary"
            />
```

And event

```
const switchType = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
   
    const currentIndex = checked.indexOf(event.target.value);
    const newChecked = [...checked];

    if (currentIndex === -1) {
      newChecked.push(event.target.value);
    } else {
      newChecked.splice(currentIndex, 1);
    }
```

**event.target.value** is undelined by red color in both variants.

Comment: Can you provide full code examples as it's not easy to debug what is going on in the example code provided. Provide the parent and checkbox components.

Comment: `const switchType = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the code you have provided is not sufficient, here's a type-safe example that I feel is what you are trying to accomplish.

I've reworked some of the code regarding the addition / removal of an item as the code provided was incomplete to make the example function, I've also removed some unecessary props in the example to make it easier to understand.

```js
import * as React from "react";

const Checkbox: React.FC<{
  value: string;
  isChecked: (value: string) => boolean;
  onChange: (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => void;
}> = ({ value, isChecked, onChange }) => {
  const checked = isChecked(value);

  return (
    <div>
      <label htmlFor={value}>{value}</label>
      <input
        id={value}
        type="checkbox"
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        checked={checked}
      />
    </div>
  );
};

function TodoList() {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState<string[]>([]);

  const onChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { value } = event.target;
    const isAlreadySelected = selected.includes(value);

    setSelected((prevState) =>
      isAlreadySelected
        ? prevState.filter((p) => p !== value)
        : [...prevState, value]
    );
  };

  const isChecked = (value: string) => {
    return selected.includes(value);
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Todo List</h1>
      <Checkbox value="Get Milk" onChange={onChange} isChecked={isChecked} />
      <Checkbox value="Get Bread" onChange={onChange} isChecked={isChecked} />
      <pre>{JSON.stringify(selected)}</pre>
    </div>
  );
}

export default TodoList;
```

Due to StackOverflow not supporting TypeScript, you can view the runnable example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-dewdney-9mm7b